# jQuery Validation - Select at least 3 fields of 20

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Hi now I search several hours for a solution. I have 20 fields (dropdowns) with the answers "yes" and "no". Now I want to validate, that the user must say to 3 of the 20 "yes". Which this are from the 20 does not matter.

For example one of the 20 dropdowns...

```
<select name="dd1" id="dd1">
<option value="yes">Yes</option>
<option value="no" selected="selected">No</option>
</select>
```

Does anyone have an idea for a solution?

For Validation I use for example this format:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#register").validate({

        rules: {

            surname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 3
            },

            messages: {
            surname: {
                required: "xxx",
                minlength: "xxx"
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
             if ( element.is(":checkbox") )
             error.appendTo(element.parent("td").next("td"));
             else if ( element.is(":radio") )
             error.appendTo(element.parent("td").next("td"));
             else
             error.appendTo( element.parent());
            }

    });

  });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( $('select.my20drops[value="yes"]').length > 3 ) {
    // do something!
}
```

Comment: How can I integrate it to my script above?
The Problem I have is, that there are also other dropdown on the site. But I only want to take it on this 20. For example all 20 have the class="my20drops".

Comment: Just add the class to the selector? I don't use the validate plugin, I always roll my own validation, but I guess you have to create a new rule, but how exactly you do that is beyond me.

Comment: I tried this but its doesn't work....

 groups:{
  
              my20drops:{ required: function(){
                    if ( $('select[value="yes"]').length > 3 ) {
      required: true
      }
              }},
  
  },

And I tried it as rule but I don't know what I must enter to say that it must be all field with class="my20drops" and not only one filed...

Comment: adeneo, [your selector always shows `"0"`](http://jsfiddle.net/acP88/).  It should be: `$('select.mydrops option[value="yes"]:selected').length`; demo here:  http://jsfiddle.net/acP88/1/

Answer (score 2):

Fixing @adeneo's selector...

```
$('select.mydrops option[value="yes"]:selected')
```

Then using the [plugin's `addMethod` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage), I created a custom rule.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/UBhce/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.validator.addMethod('customrule', function(value, element, param) {
        return ( $('select.mydrops option[value="yes"]:selected').length >= param ); 
    }, "please select 'yes' to at least {0} items");

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        groups: {
            whatever: "dd1 dd2 dd3 dd4"  // grouping all messages into one
        }
    });

    $('.mydrops').each(function() { // apply rule to all selects at once
        $(this).rules('add', {
            customrule: 3  // using a parameter for number of required selects
        });
    });

});
```

I also added `class="mydrops"` to all `select` elements and made sure all `id`'s and `names`'s are unique.

```
<select name="dd1" id="dd1" class="mydrops">
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="no" selected="selected">No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your perfect help. It works! But two questions I still have. In my script I get the error message near every dropdown and not like in your demo only once. 

How can I integrate this?
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    if ( element.is(":selected") )
          error.appendTo(element.parent("td").next("td"));

Comment: Can it be that two   $(document).ready(function(){
    
    $("#makleranmeldung").validate({

make trouble? Because if I remove the second script the script you post work fine. What can I do?

Comment: @TrivoXx, as mentioned in code comments above, the `groups` option is used to lump all the messages into one.  It's an arbitrary name followed by a "space separated list of field `name`'s".  See documentation for `groups` option on this page:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions  Simply use `groups` along with `errorPlacement`:  http://jsfiddle.net/UBhce/1/

Comment: @TrivoXx, Since I correctly answered your original question, please "accept" my answer by clicking the green checkmark.  Thanks!

Comment: `if (element.is("select"))` would contain the correct selector for a `<select>` element.