# jquery-validate: validate if the sum of two fields is greater than X

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery-validate and I am trying to validate that the value of two fields (**participants_adults** and **participats_child**) is greater than X (a number). As an additional challenge, the second field (**participats_child**) may or may not exist, so if it does not exist the validation should only take the first field (**participats_adults**) into account.

I have this html:

```
<select name="participants_adults" class="valid">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
</select>

<select name="participants_child" class="valid">
   <option>0</option>
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
</select>
```

And the jQuery code I have so far is this:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $('#booking_form').validate({
    rules: {
      participants_adults: {
        required: {
               depends: function(element) {
                return (parseInt($('[name="participants_adults"]').val()) + parseInt($('[name="participants_child"]').val()) > 2);
                 }
               }
      }
    }
   });
 });
```

I am not being successful at achieving this validation. Anybody can help, please?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than a conditional rule, create a custom method [using `addMethod` as per the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/).

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("myMethod", function(value, element, params) {
    // your function
    // return false to display the error message
    // return true to pass validation
}, "this is the error message");
```

The function's arguments are defined as follows:

**value**
Type: String
the current value of the validated element

**element**
Type: Element
the element to be validated

**params**
Type: String
parameters specified for the method, e.g. for `min: 5`, the parameter is `5`, for `range: [1, 5]` it’s `[1, 5]`

---

Also see these answers for more examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19096923/594235

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15594795/594235

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know how to call the method but your first example helped me.